# Statistics about flights arriving behind schedule?

Tags: air-travel, planning, statistics

I am planning a trip and it is important to me to arrive on time, so I want to calculate how much hours behind schedule can the plane arrive. For example, if I want to be at the destination airport at 12:00, and I take a flight that is supposed to arrive at 11:00, what are the chances that the flight actually arrives after 12:00?

This probably depends on the origin, destination, airplane, etc., so I am looking for statistical data tables. Where can I find such tables?